# Java's DecimalFormat parses incorrect decimal number as integer

Tags: java, formatting, format, decimalformat

Receive all a greeting.

I need to validate that a text corresponds to a number. The project locale is **es_CO**. The problem I have now is that texts with a period used as a decimal separator are parsed to integer numbers, when it should be an error, since in the aforementioned location, the decimal separator is a comma.

For example:

- Locale: `es_CO`
- Pattern: `###.###,##`
- Text: `1.48`
- Number result: `148.0`

Source code:

```
Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("es", "CO");
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(defaultLocale);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
decimalFormat.applyLocalizedPattern("###.###,##");
Number number = decimalFormat.parse("1.48"); // Here I would expect an exception to be generated.
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem to be a bug in DecimalFormat.  One way to work around it is to use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("es", "CO");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1.48");
scanner.useLocale(defaultLocale);
Number number = scanner.nextDouble();
```